# UIWebView History If Statement

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview, webkit

How can I detect the last page viewed in a UIWebView? Basically I want to say, **if** (in an *if statement*) the last page viewed in the UIWebView was @"http://www.example.com" and the current UIWebView page is @"http://www.lalala.com" then …… and my action.

Thank you,

James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the webview delegate's webViewDidFinishLoad:, get the url of the last loaded page (by examining webview's request property) and store it in some property. Then use that property in your if statement.

Edit: add a property (lets say to the UIWebView delegate class):

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSURL* lastLoadedURL;
```

Then add this method:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
self.lastLoadedURL = [webView.request URL];
}
```

So whenever you need to check the last loaded page you'd do something like this:

```
if([[self.lastLoadedURL lastPathComponent] isEqualToString:@"somepage.html"]) {
//do stuff
}
```

or if you're not in the UIWebView delegate class, you'd need to replace self.lastLoadedURL with (delegateClassInstance).lastLoadedURL.

Comment: sorry, do you mind providing a bit of sample code as I'm not quite sure how to do all this :S